# How to know java JRadio button is unselected

Tags: java, swing, toggle, actionlistener, jradiobutton

I have to make three radio buttons. On selection of the third radio button I have to show some text boxes. I also have to immediately remove the text boxes when the third radio button is unselected and any one of the other two is selected. I am looking for a callback when the JRadio button is unselected. I have supplied an ActionListener but it gets called only on selection and not on unselection. How do I achieve this toggle functionality with java JRadio button.

```
radioCustomButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            System.out.println("Callback called");
            if(radioCustomButton.isSelected()){
                System.out.println("Checked");
            }
        }
    });
```

This is printing "Callback called" only on check but not on uncheck. I have added this radioCustomButton object in ButtonGroup as well.

I am left with the only option of supplying  action listener to other two radio buttons and then write code to remove the text boxes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use an ActionListener to check when the button is selected.

Instead use an `ItemListener` and you will be notified when the button is selected and unselected.

See [How to Write an Item Listener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/itemlistener.html) for an example.